# command to adjust alternate rows in one row and vice

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

Input

```
mykulls1177  MemTotal:     41052672 kB
MemFree:        647480 kB
sandpit  MemTotal:     32959008 kB
MemFree:        227400 kB
greuat  MemTotal:     41052672 kB
MemFree:        336684 kB
mykulls1765  MemTotal:       263771772 kB
MemFree:        104100068 kB
mykulls1766  MemTotal:       528541224 kB
MemFree:        363083156 kB
mykulls1767  MemTotal:       528541312 kB
MemFree:         7703888 kB
mykulls1768  MemTotal:       98289912 kB
MemFree:         3102528 kB
mykulls1769  MemTotal:       98290004 kB
MemFree:         4148740 kB
mykulls1770  MemTotal:       164479104 kB
MemFree:        63983920 kB
mykulls1771  MemTotal:       164479104 kB
MemFree:        33030748 kB
mykulls1773  MemTotal:       98288948 kB
MemFree:        22037620 kB
```

Output I want

```
mykulls1177  MemTotal:     41052672 kB MemFree:        647480 kB
sandpit  MemTotal:     32959008 kB     MemFree:        227400 kB
greuat  MemTotal:     41052672 kB      MemFree:        336684 kB
mykulls1765  MemTotal:       263771772 kB MemFree:        104100068 kB
mykulls1766  MemTotal:       528541224 kB MemFree:        363083156 kB
mykulls1767  MemTotal:       528541312 kB MemFree:         7703888 kB
mykulls1768  MemTotal:       98289912 kB MemFree:         3102528 kB
mykulls1769  MemTotal:       98290004 kB MemFree:         4148740 kB
mykulls1770  MemTotal:       164479104 kB MemFree:        63983920 kB
mykulls1771  MemTotal:       164479104 kB MemFree:        33030748 kB
mykulls1773  MemTotal:       98288948 kB  MemFree:        22037620 kB
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: If it's only about joining lines  take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/how-to-merge-every-two-lines-into-one-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

Use below command it worked fine for me

command

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /'  filename
```

output

```
mykulls1177  MemTotal:     41052672 kB MemFree:        647480 kB
sandpit  MemTotal:     32959008 kB MemFree:        227400 kB
greuat  MemTotal:     41052672 kB MemFree:        336684 kB
mykulls1765  MemTotal:       263771772 kB MemFree:        104100068 kB
mykulls1766  MemTotal:       528541224 kB MemFree:        363083156 kB
mykulls1767  MemTotal:       528541312 kB MemFree:         7703888 kB
mykulls1768  MemTotal:       98289912 kB MemFree:         3102528 kB
mykulls1769  MemTotal:       98290004 kB MemFree:         4148740 kB
mykulls1770  MemTotal:       164479104 kB MemFree:        63983920 kB
mykulls1771  MemTotal:       164479104 kB MemFree:        33030748 kB
mykulls1773  MemTotal:       98288948 kB MemFree:        22037620 kB
```